# MySQL: Writing table into csv file

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query which selects the columns from a MySQL table and write it into a csv file.

```
 (select 'tempid', 'region', 'puma')
 union all
 select * from (select tempid, region, puma_2000 from tableA order by tempid  limit 
 4000000) a
  into outfile 'c:/models/output.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  optionally ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

It gives me "error 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax.". I tried a few changes but nothing seemed to work. The MySQL version I am using is 5.5. Do you see an obvious error in the query?

Comment: The error resolved once the parenthesis around select was removed.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
select * from (select tempid, region, puma_2000 from tableA order by tempid,  limit
```

try removing the comma after tempid and before limit:

```
select * from (select tempid, region, puma_2000 from tableA order by tempid limit
```

Comment: There was a typo in my question. The comma has been removed and I still get the same error.